# Hystrix - slow response on first request

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I have a Spring Boot REST services which uses Hystrix from Spring Cloud Netflix. I noticed that the first call to the interface needs much time to process, since the first call to the method which is isolated with Hystrix takes 2-3 seconds for the Hystrix to load.

This is the code:

```
@HystrixCommand(ignoreExceptions = { BusinessException.class,
                    TechnicalException.class }, fallbackMethod = "testFall", commandProperties = {
@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "15000") })
public void test() throws BusinessException, TechnicalException {
    System.out.println("Inside");
}
```

Is there a way to preload Hystrix so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: I don't think it is true. Everything which is needed to enable circuit breaker is setup while starting.

Comment: I thought that too, but its clearly visible that from the moment the method is called to the moment the first line of code in the method is executed, 2-3 seconds will pass...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue (loosing "only" 500 ms).

It happens when the HystrixCommandGroup is initialized the first time. Most time is lost when creating the HystrixMetrics:
[hystrix profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/647Ke.png)

I've created an issue: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1832

Unfortunately the HystrixCommand (and within the HystrixCommandGroup) is only initialized when the annotated method is called. You cannot precompile it. As a workaround you could use the abstract HystrixCommand class instead of the annotation and create a dummy instance at startup. e.g.:

```
public class TestCommand extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    static {
        new TestCommand();
    }

    protected TestCommand() {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("mygroup"));
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```